# How to efficiently clone and truncate a BTreeMap?

Tags: rust, iterator, btreemap

I'd like to efficiently, preferably in a functional way, truncate an existing BTreeMap from a reference and return a cloned, truncated BTreeMap of the same key-value pairs.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

/// I want to return a BTreeMap containing only the first 2 keys.
fn truncate(b: &BTreeMap<u32, u32>) -> BTreeMap<u32, u32> {
    b.iter().take(2).cloned().collect()
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = BTreeMap::new();
    b.insert(1, 1);
    b.insert(2, 1);
    b.insert(3, 1);
    let t = truncate(&b);
}
```

The error message:

> expected an iterator that yields `&_`, but it yields
> `(&u32, &u32)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be useful to consider all error messages ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db708bf9355582e994f9643c2c6c72ba)):

```
error[E0271]: expected `std::iter::Take<std::collections::btree_map::Iter<'_, u32, u32>>` to be an iterator that yields `&_`, but it yields `(&u32, &u32)`
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     b.iter().take(2).cloned().collect()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------ required by a bound introduced by this call
  |     |
  |     expected reference, found tuple
  |
  = note: expected reference `&_`
                 found tuple `(&u32, &u32)`
note: required by a bound in `cloned`
 --> /rustc/d5a82bbd26e1ad8b7401f6a718a9c57c96905483/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:3271:32
  |
  = note: required by this bound in `cloned`
```

`.cloned()` will turn an iterator over `&T` into an iterator over `T`. But you have an iterator over `(&u32, &u32)`, which `.cloned()` simply can't be used on. Even if you had `&(&u32, &u32)`, you'd only get `(&u32, &u32)`.

In this case, there is no neat function that you could use to take care of stripping the references, you'll need to write it yourself.

```rust
b.iter().take(2).map(|(&a, &b)| (a, b)).collect()
```